# SWR doesn't work when window loses focus in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, fetch, swr

I am using SWR in nextjs:

```js
const fetcher = () => {
  const response = axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/model", {
  }).then(r => r.data)
  return response;
};

export default function Model() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR("/api/model", fetcher);
  return <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>}
```

My `/api/model` is `GET` request to my database, and the database updates the value every second.

However, if I stay on the page, the `JSON.stringify(data)` won't even change; once I switch to another tap or click the background of my computer, then click back the page, the value change instantly(I don't know how to explain this kind of situation).

I want the data to keep updating when I stay on the website without any action like WebSocket. Can I do it using SWR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have experienced "revalidate on focus" strategy, when the tab is focused the data will be revalidated. This option is enabled by default.

If you want to refetch the data based on some interval you can use `refreshInterval` option, example from the docs:

```
useSWR('/api/todos', fetcher, { refreshInterval: 1000 })
```

[More info in the docs as always](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#revalidate-on-interval)

Comment: Thank you, and may I ask even though I set a small number in `refreshInterval`, I checked the update time in inspect->network, and the time is still around 300ms(size 350B), is it mostly because the database query is slow?

Comment: `refreshInterval` is how often you client side code refetches the data. In network tab you see the time it took to perform this request and receive an answer from the server. So yes, probably you db is slow. For the future keep in mind the scaling of the app, what would happen if you have let's say 100 users, each of them requests updates every second.